# How to get statistics that index updated or not while DML operation in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How to get statistics that index is updated or not while DML operation in PostgreSQL?

In MS SQL there is DMV to get this details. Is there any way to get same details in Postgresql, any statistics view ?

Comment: Yes this is the by nature in database. However, actually I have prepared partitioned table and same index on all partitions and I want to check index is  updated  for all partition or only one partition ? Logically it should update only one partition in which data are inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: @wildplasser: there are [HOT updates](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches I can think of.

1. **using SQL**

   To find out how many modifications affecting indexes a table received in the current database transaction, you can run

   ```
   SELECT pg_stat_get_xact_tuples_deleted('table_name'::regclass)
        + pg_stat_get_xact_tuples_inserted('table_name'::regclass)
        + pg_stat_get_xact_tuples_updated('table_name'::regclass)
        - pg_stat_get_xact_tuples_hot_updated('table_name'::regclass);
   ```

   Unless an index is partial, it will have received as data modifications as the query returns.
2. **using the transaction log**

   First, find out the file that belongs to your index:

   ```
   SELECT format(
             '%s/%s/%s',
             (SELECT oid FROM pg_tablespace WHERE spcname = 'pg_default'),
             (SELECT oid FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'test'),
             (SELECT relfilenode FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'uni_id_key')
          );

         format      
   ------------------
    1663/16384/16390
   (1 row)
   ```

   Then find out the current transaction log segment:

   ```
   SELECT pg_walfile_name(pg_current_wal_lsn());

        pg_walfile_name      
   --------------------------
    00000001000000010000006D
   (1 row)
   ```

   Locate the appropriate WAL file and run pg_waldump on it:

   ```
   pg_waldump pg_wal/00000001000000010000006D 2>/dev/null | grep 1663/16384/16390

   rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):     53/   213, tx:     374500, lsn: 1/6D764F30, prev 1/6D764E18, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 3, blkref #0: rel 1663/16384/16390 blk 1 FPW
   rmgr: Btree       len (rec/tot):     53/   233, tx:     374533, lsn: 1/6D773830, prev 1/6D7736F0, desc: INSERT_LEAF off 4, blkref #0: rel 1663/16384/16390 blk 1 FPW
   ```

   So there are two modifications of that index in the current WAL segment.

I am aware that both solutions are not exactly what you want, but I don't think you can do better.